# Trocar o primeiro caractere de uma string pelo último caractere em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
def troca(s):
    letra1 = s[0]
    letra2 = s[-1]
    s = s.replace(s[0], letra2)
    s = s.replace(s[-1], letra1)
    return s

troca ('bar')
```

Como podem ver, eu forneço como argumento pra minha função `troca` a string `'bar'`. O resultado que eu espero que a função retorne é `'rab'`(ou seja, a primeira letra trocada pela última), mas ao executar o código, tenho como retorno `'bab'`.
No python tutor, vejo que o código é executado normalmente até o segundo `replace`. no primeiro `replace`, a minha string está `'rar'`(até aí tudo bem, troquei a primeira letra da string pela última), mas no segundo, a minha string simplesmente fica `'bab'`, ou seja, ele troca a primeira e a última letra, todas pela primeira. Por que isso acontece? Obrigado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O método [`string.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) substitui **todas** as ocorrências de uma substring, não apenas uma. Assim, se sua string é `rar` e você pede para substituir o `r` pelo `b`, todos os `r`s serão substituídos, e o resultado será `bab`.

Note que, mesmo que somente uma única ocorrência fosse substituída, você não especificou qual... de modo que o primeiro `r` em `rar` seria a primeira opção a ser considerada, fazendo sua string retornar para `bar` - por exemplo, se você fizesse `"rar".replace("r", "b", 1)`.

Se você quer substituir uma ocorrência específica na string, acesse-a por índice e não por conteúdo. Há poucas opções para isso, de modo que eu usaria o operador *slice* junto com uma concatenação:

```
def troca(s):
    return s[-1] + s[1:-1] + s[0] if len(s) > 1 else s
```

Comment: Estranho, eu achava que estava acessando pelo índice. Por exemplo, na linha `s = s.replace(s[-1], letra1)`, eu achava que ele substituía a última posição da string pela letra que eu armazenei na variável `letra1`, e não todas a letras iguais, já que eu estava fornecendo uma posição.

Comment: É que a posição que você está fornecendo `-1` está sendo usado exclusivamente em `s`, para indicar sua última letra - essa sim sendo usada no `replace`. Em outras palavras, `s[-1] ==> "r"` acontece primeiro, e `s.replace("r", letra1)` acontece segundo.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal usar `string slicing` para solucionar seu problema:

```
>>> str = "aeiou"
>>> str[-1:] + str[1:-1] + str[:1]
'ueioa'
```

Referência: http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/

Answer (score -4):

Tem outra forma também, derrepente pode te ajudar porém a diferença e que ele escreve de trás para frente a palavra.

```
>>> def troca(s):
    return s[::-1]

>>> troca("bar")
'rab'
>>> troca("arara")  #Famosa palavra Palíndrome
'arara'
>>> troca("python")
'nohtyp'
```

Espero que te ajude e outras visões.

Answer (score -5):

Uma solução mais simplificada:

function nomeProprio(name){
return name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1).toLowerCase()
}

Comment: Douglas, viu que a pergunta é sobre Python? O código que postou está em outra linguagem.